# how fix this extjs layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

This is my ext code

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Customer Information',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    floating: true,
    renderTo: document.body,
    frame: true,
    collapsible: true,
    closable: true,
    defaults: { labelWidth: 90 },
    items: [{
                xtype: 'image',
                id: 'profile_pic',
                name: 'profile_pic',
                style: { display: 'block', margin: 'auto' },                
                src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png',               
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'ID',
            name: 'viewer_id',
            id: 'viewer_id',
            padding: '5 0 0 0',
            fieldCls: 'specialfield',
            value: ''       
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'viewer_name',
            id: 'viewer_name',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            value: '',
            width: 280
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Member ID',
            name: 'viewer_mem_id',
            id: 'viewer_mem_id',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            width: 280          
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Address',
            name: 'viewer_address',
            id: 'viewer_address',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            width: 280          
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Phone [Home]',
            name: 'viewer_phone_home',
            id: 'viewer_phone_home',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            width: 280  

        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Phone [Mobile]',
            name: 'viewer_phone_mobile',
            id: 'viewer_phone_mobile',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            width: 280      
        },{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Phone [Work]',
            name: 'viewer_phone_work',
            id: 'viewer_phone_work',
            fieldCls: 'fieldcolor',
            width: 280          
        }]
});
```

problem is first time it loads it shows like this

[image]

once the image loaded and then refresh it gives me the layout i needed

[image]

i guess the problem is happening due to image size. how to fix this issue?

sorry for the bad english

Regards

Comment: try to add `autoHeight: true`

Comment: tried no luck with autoheight :(

Comment: If the height of image is not changing you can set the height of image: `height:90` inside the declaring the image: http://jsfiddle.net/6NK7n/

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply. problem is image height is not fixed :( it may change between 150 to 200px though

Comment: Oh... But maybe if you set some middle-value, say 175, the image will resize to fit the height.

Comment: yeah. so far the best way is to set height like this. Thanks sigurd

Comment: You're welcome. :) I will form this solution as an answer for not to confuse other people.

Comment: Here is a demo of the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/wvc4w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From the comments above.*

If the height of image is not changing you can set the height of image: `height:90` inside the declaring the image: [jsfiddle.net/6NK7n/](http://jsfiddle.net/6NK7n/)

Anyway, the image will be resized to fit the height you set.

Answer (score 3):

Found the correct way to do it by adding a listener and bind load event to element

```
var v_profile_image = Ext.widget('image', {
  src: '',
  style: { display: 'block', margin: 'auto' },
  name: 'profile_pic'
});

v_profile_image.on('load', function(e) {
  this.up('panel').doLayout();
}, v_profile_image, { element: 'el' });
```